# Is there a tool like Microsoft's "SQL Server Profiler" for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, profiler, tools

While developing on MySQL I really miss being able to fire up a profiler. I find [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) is a good enough replacement for Query Analyzer but have not found a tool that works like SQL profiler.

For the MySQL folk who have not seen Microsoft's [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx), here is a screenshot

[image: profiler sql]

At my previous job we had a tool that [trumped SQL Profiler](http://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/05/11/15.aspx) and even gave us stack traces

[image: altiris profiler]

Does anyone know of any tools like the ones I mentioned that works with MySQL.

(FYI, I can get the Altiris Profiler to work with MySQL but it will involve running Windows furthermore its not really a Symantec sku so licensing is really tricky)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such tool.

Comment: Agreed. I've found that most MySQL developers/administrators have never spent much time with Microsoft SQL Server and don't realize how incredible the MS stack is for development. Every MySQL query tool I've seen depends on polling, but SQL Server allows you watch nearly everything that's happening with the database in real-time. There is nothing that comes close to the detail of SQL Server Profiler because MySQL simply doesn't support it.

Answer (score 19):

MySQL has never come up with Query Profiling. Now that MySQL is being grandfathered by Oracle, I know this will continue to be the case.

Yet, all hope is not lost.

Since 2007, Percona has come up with some absolutely marvelous tools for everything a Developer and DBA would want, including Query Profiling.

Percona's first set of tools, known as [**MAATKIT**](http://www.maatkit.org/), created a realm for the serious user of MySQL. [*It features many things*](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/), such as:

- Query Profiling
- Replication Heartbeat
- Replication Slave Management
- Table Checksum and Synchronization

Percona has recently forked MAATKIT into a more up-to-date set of tools, [known today as **Percona Toolkit**](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/). These tools picked up where MAATKIT left off by expanding the realm of activity for the serious MySQL user to include things such:

- Foreign Key Error Checking
- Online Schema Changing
- Visual Explain Plans
- and more ...

Getting back to the original question, the tools out there for query profiling are

- [pt-query-advisor](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-query-advisor.html)
- [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-query-digest.html)
- [mk-query-profiler](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-profiler.html) (for MAATKIT users)
- [mk-query-digest](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html) (for MAATKIT users)

Here is an example of the kind of rich information that can come from using one of these tools:

I helped a client implement mk-query-digest to report the 20 worst-performing queries every 20 minutes. [**I got the idea from this YouTube video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXwg1fiUF68&feature=colike). The client would move any bad query's output to memcached thus lowering the incidence of the query's taking a toll on the the database.

Here is the script I made to call mk-query-digest (examing the processlist only)

```
#!/bin/sh

RUNFILE=/tmp/QueriesAreBeingDigested.txt
if [ -f ${RUNFILE} ] ; then exit ; fi

MKDQ=/usr/local/sbin/mk-query-digest
RUNTIME=${1}
COPIES_TO_KEEP=${2}
DBVIP=${3}

WHICH=/usr/bin/which
DATE=`${WHICH} date`
ECHO=`${WHICH} echo`
HEAD=`${WHICH} head`
TAIL=`${WHICH} tail`
AWK=`${WHICH} awk`
SED=`${WHICH} sed`
CAT=`${WHICH} cat`
WC=`${WHICH} wc`
RM=`${WHICH} rm | ${TAIL} -1 | ${AWK} '{print $1}'`
LS=`${WHICH} ls | ${TAIL} -1 | ${AWK} '{print $1}'`

HAS_THE_DBVIP=`/sbin/ip addr show | grep "scope global secondary" | grep -c "${DBVIP}"`
if [ ${HAS_THE_DBVIP} -eq 1 ] ; then exit ; fi

DT=`${DATE} +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
UNIQUETAG=`${ECHO} ${SSH_CLIENT}_${SSH_CONNECTION}_${DT} | ${SED} 's/\./ /g' | ${SED} 's/ //g'`

cd /root/QueryDigest
OUTFILE=QP_${DT}.txt
HOSTADDR=${DBVIP}
${MKDQ} --processlist h=${HOSTADDR},u=queryprofiler,p=queryprofiler --run-time=${RUNTIME} > ${OUTFILE}

#
# Rotate out Old Copies
#

QPFILES=QPFiles.txt
QPFILES2ZAP=QPFiles2Zap.txt
${LS} QP_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt > ${QPFILES}

LINECOUNT=`${WC} -l < ${QPFILES}`
if [ ${LINECOUNT} -gt ${COPIES_TO_KEEP} ]
then
        (( DIFF = LINECOUNT - COPIES_TO_KEEP ))
        ${HEAD} -${DIFF} < ${QPFILES} > ${QPFILES2ZAP}
        for QPFILETOZAP in `${CAT} ${QPFILES2ZAP}`
        do
                ${RM} ${QPFILETOZAP}
        done
fi

rm -f ${QPFILES2ZAP}
rm -f ${QPFILES}
rm -f ${RUNFILE}
```

Here is the user I made to connect to mysql using mk-query-digest

```
GRANT PROCESS ON *.* TO 'queryprofiler'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'queryprofiler';
```

Here is the crontab I ran every 20 minutes (less 10 seconds) keeping the last 144 copies (which is 48 hours of profiling)

```
*/20 * * * * /root/QueryDigest/ExecQueryDigest.sh 1190s 144 10.1.1.8
```

### The incredible part: The output of mk-query-digest

Here is a profile that ran 2011-12-28 11:20:00 for 1190 sec (20 min less 10 sec)

The last 22 lines

```
# Rank Query ID           Response time    Calls   R/Call     Item
# ==== ================== ================ ======= ========== ====
#    1 0x5E994008E9543B29    40.3255 11.2%     101   0.399263 SELECT schedule_occurrence schedule_eventschedule schedule_event schedule_eventtype schedule_event schedule_eventtype schedule_occurrence.start
#    2 0x392F6DA628C7FEBD    33.9181  9.4%      17   1.995184 SELECT mt_entry mt_objecttag
#    3 0x6C6318E56E149036    26.4695  7.3%     102   0.259505 SELECT schedule_occurrence schedule_eventschedule schedule_event schedule_eventtype schedule_event schedule_eventtype schedule_occurrence.start
#    4 0x00F66961DAE6FFB2    25.5472  7.1%      55   0.464495 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#    5 0x99E13015BFF1E75E    22.3618  6.2%     199   0.112371 SELECT mt_entry mt_objecttag
#    6 0x84DD09F0FC444677    22.3516  6.2%      39   0.573118 SELECT mt_entry
#    7 0x440EBDBCEDB88725    21.1817  5.9%      36   0.588380 SELECT mt_entry
#    8 0x8D258C584B858811    17.2402  4.8%      37   0.465951 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#    9 0x4E2CB0F4CAFD1400    16.9768  4.7%      40   0.424419 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#   10 0x377E0D0898266FDD    16.6979  4.6%     150   0.111319 SELECT polls_pollquestion mt_category
#   11 0x3B9686D98BB8E054    16.2089  4.5%      32   0.506529 SELECT mt_entry mt_objecttag mt_tag
#   12 0x97F670B604A85608    15.6158  4.3%      34   0.459287 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#   13 0x3F5557DA231225EB    14.4309  4.0%      36   0.400859 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#   14 0x191D660A10738896    13.1220  3.6%      31   0.423290 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#   15 0xF88F7421DD88036D    12.1261  3.4%      61   0.198788 SELECT mt_entry mt_blog mt_objecttag mt_tag mt_author
#   16 0xA909BF76E7051792    10.3971  2.9%      53   0.196172 SELECT mt_entry mt_objecttag mt_tag
#   17 0x3D42D07A335ED983     9.1424  2.5%      20   0.457121 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#   18 0x59F43B57DD43F2BD     9.0533  2.5%      21   0.431111 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
#   19 0x7961BD4C76277EB7     8.5564  2.4%      47   0.182052 INSERT UNION UPDATE UNION mt_session
#   20 0x173EB4903F3B6DAC     8.5394  2.4%      22   0.388153 SELECT mt_entry mt_placement mt_category
```

Notice that this the list of the 20 worst-performing queries based on Query Response Time divided by the Number of Times the query was called.

Looking at Query ID #1, which is `0x5E994008E9543B29`, we locate that Query ID in the output file and here is the report for that particular query:

```
# Query 1: 0.09 QPS, 0.03x concurrency, ID 0x5E994008E9543B29 at byte 0 __
# This item is included in the report because it matches --limit.
#              pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# Count          4     101
# Exec time      7     40s   303ms      1s   399ms   992ms   198ms   293ms
# Lock time      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
# Users                  1      mt
# Hosts                101 10.64.95.73:33750 (1), 10.64.95.73:34452 (1), 10.64.95.73:38440 (1)... 97 more
# Databases              1     mt1
# Time range 1325089201 to 1325090385
# bytes          0 273.60k   2.71k   2.71k   2.71k   2.62k       0   2.62k
# id             4 765.11M   7.57M   7.58M   7.58M   7.29M    0.12   7.29M
# Query_time distribution
#   1us
#  10us
# 100us
#   1ms
#  10ms
# 100ms  ################################################################
#    1s  ######
#  10s+
# Tables
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `mt1` LIKE 'schedule_occurrence'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `mt1`.`schedule_occurrence`\G
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `mt1` LIKE 'schedule_eventschedule'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `mt1`.`schedule_eventschedule`\G
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `mt1` LIKE 'schedule_event'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `mt1`.`schedule_event`\G
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `mt1` LIKE 'schedule_eventtype'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `mt1`.`schedule_eventtype`\G
#    SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `schedule_occurrence` LIKE 'start'\G
#    SHOW CREATE TABLE `schedule_occurrence`.`start`\G
# EXPLAIN
SELECT `schedule_occurrence`.`id`, `schedule_occurrence`.`schedule_id`, `schedule_occurrence`.`event_id`, `schedule_occurrence`.`start`, `schedule_occurrence`.`end`, `schedule_occurrence`.`cancelled`, `schedule_occurrence`.`original_start`, `schedule_occurrence`.`original_end`, `schedule_occurrence`.`all_day`, `schedule_occurrence`.`ongoing`, `schedule_occurrence`.`featured`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`id`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`event_id`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`start`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`end`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`all_day`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`ongoing`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`min_date_calculated`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`max_date_calculated`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`rule`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`end_recurring_period`, `schedule_eventschedule`.`textual_description`, `schedule_event`.`id`, `schedule_event`.`title`, `schedule_event`.`slug`, `schedule_event`.`description`, `schedule_event`.`host_id`, `schedule_event`.`cost`, `schedule_event`.`age_restrictions`, `schedule_event`.`more_info`, `schedule_event`.`photo_id`, `schedule_event`.`contact_email`, `schedule_event`.`event_type_id`, `schedule_event`.`featured`, `schedule_event`.`staff_pick`, `schedule_event`.`futuremost`, `schedule_event`.`creator_id`, `schedule_event`.`created_on`, `schedule_event`.`allow_comments`, `schedule_event`.`mt_entry`, `schedule_eventtype`.`id`, `schedule_eventtype`.`parent_id`, `schedule_eventtype`.`name`, `schedule_eventtype`.`slug`, `schedule_eventtype`.`lft`, `schedule_eventtype`.`rght`, `schedule_eventtype`.`tree_id`, `schedule_eventtype`.`level`, T5.`id`, T5.`title`, T5.`slug`, T5.`description`, T5.`host_id`, T5.`cost`, T5.`age_restrictions`, T5.`more_info`, T5.`photo_id`, T5.`contact_email`, T5.`event_type_id`, T5.`featured`, T5.`staff_pick`, T5.`futuremost`, T5.`creator_id`, T5.`created_on`, T5.`allow_comments`, T5.`mt_entry`, T6.`id`, T6.`parent_id`, T6.`name`, T6.`slug`, T6.`lft`, T6.`rght`, T6.`tree_id`, T6.`level` FROM `schedule_occurrence` INNER JOIN `schedule_eventschedule` ON (`schedule_occurrence`.`schedule_id` = `schedule_eventschedule`.`id`) INNER JOIN `schedule_event` ON (`schedule_eventschedule`.`event_id` = `schedule_event`.`id`) INNER JOIN `schedule_eventtype` ON (`schedule_event`.`event_type_id` = `schedule_eventtype`.`id`) INNER JOIN `schedule_event` T5 ON (`schedule_occurrence`.`event_id` = T5.`id`) INNER JOIN `schedule_eventtype` T6 ON (T5.`event_type_id` = T6.`id`) WHERE (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM `schedule_occurrence`.`start`) = 8 AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM `schedule_occurrence`.`start`) = 6 AND `schedule_occurrence`.`start` BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' and '2011-12-31 23:59:59.99') ORDER BY `schedule_occurrence`.`ongoing` ASC, `schedule_occurrence`.`all_day` DESC, `schedule_occurrence`.`start` ASC\G
```

Although the histogram is text-based, it gives an accurate picture of the query's overall performance, sometimes running over 1 sec, and most of the time between 0.01 and 0.1 seconds. From here, one can proceed to do performance tuning by refactoring the query, placing query results in memcached, adding missing or covering indexes, etc.

### CONCLUSION

IMHO If Percona ever placed the profiler tools into a Windows GUI, it would easily rival Microsoft's SQL Server Profiler.

Defense Rests !!!

Comment: IMHO JetProfiler looks like what Percona Tools combined graphically would be. Each have nuances one over the other. Linux users and command-line people would be satisfied with Percona Tools or MAATKIT. JetProfiler eliminates having to be as DB in-depth plus the Windows graphical advantage of a MONyog at your disposal.

Answer (score 9):

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263/is-there-a-profiler-equivalent-for-mysql#340055) about [Jet Profiler for MySQL](http://www.jetprofiler.com/)

Comment: Not bad, but also doesn't show the queries that are run.  Instead, it shows "top queries".

Answer (score 5):

[MySQL Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) combined with the [GUI MySQL tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) is probably about as close as you can get to the SQL Server Profiler tool

Comment: Ouch, there is no GUI there ...

Comment: Worse yet, it still doesn't show the actually history of the traffic.  Wow, Microsoft blows the socks off Oracle on this one!

Answer (score 5):

The best out-of-the-box solutions I've found are to use a combination of the slow query log (which sucks compared to Profiler), and just running Wireshark on port 3306 (which *really* sucks compared to Profiler, and won't work if you're encrypting connections).

There's also SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST, which is like a reduced combination of sys.dm_exec_sessions and sys.dm_exec_requests (with a little sys.dm_exec_sql_text thrown in).

Answer (score 5):

If you need to profile a single application, and not all databases present on MySQL, you will find [Neor Profile SQL](http://www.profilesql.com) useful.

Answer (score 4):

We have 6 large servers running various releases of MySQL from 4.1.22 through 5.1. [Jet profiler](http://mysql-tools.com/en/overview-mysql-tools/73-other/91-review-jet-profiler-for-mysql.html) good tool that  allow us to graphically see the status of all the servers at a glance. 
[Visual profiler http://tinyurl.com/profiler-png](http://tinyurl.com/profiler-png)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the closest thing to this is [Optimizer Trace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-tracing-typical-usage.html) (new in 5.6).

Another example might be [`SHOW PROFILES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profiles.html) (5.1+), or [`performance_schema`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html), which has statement level analysis from MySQL 5.6+.

Answer (score 3):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263/is-there-a-profiler-equivalent-for-mysql#284632) about MySql profiler [LogMonitor](http://www.sharewareplaza.com/Log-Monitor-download_36821.html)