# How to improve MySQL Server Performance..?

Tags: mysql, performance, index, mysql-5.5, optimization

As a MySQL DBA most of the times we are supposed to optimize a poorly performing MySQL Servers.

Now my question is where to start from like we will need to find out many things as

```
1.Find the duplicate indexes.
2.Find unused indexes on the basis of selectivity.
3.Monitor the Server Parameters(What should be important parameters).
4.Execute MySQL Server performance tuning script.
5.Slow logs
```

So what should be order of examining the server and what should be exact things that should be monitored/analysed for improving the Performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Finding Duplicate Indexes

Back in January 2012, [@gbn answer a question about duplicate indexes where he presented 2 views that came from **Ronald Bradford's blog**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11705/877). I combined the two views into a single query to present duplicate indexes as follows:

```
SELECT
    ndx1.TABLE_SCHEMA,ndx1.TABLE_NAME,
    CASE 
        WHEN ndx1.COLUMNS = ndx2.COLUMNS
        AND (ndx1.IS_UNIQUE = ndx2.IS_UNIQUE) 
        THEN GREATEST(ndx1.INDEX_NAME, ndx2.INDEX_NAME) 
        ELSE ndx1.INDEX_NAME 
    END REDUNDANT_INDEX_NAME,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
        CASE 
            WHEN ndx1.COLUMNS = ndx2.COLUMNS
            AND (ndx1.IS_UNIQUE = ndx2.IS_UNIQUE) 
            THEN LEAST(ndx1.INDEX_NAME, ndx2.INDEX_NAME) 
            ELSE ndx2.INDEX_NAME 
        END
    ) INDEX_NAME 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME,INDEX_TYPE,
        IF(NON_UNIQUE, 'NO', 'YES') IS_UNIQUE,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`',COLUMN_NAME,'`')
        ORDER BY IF(INDEX_TYPE='BTREE',SEQ_IN_INDEX,0), COLUMN_NAME
        ) COLUMNS 
    FROM
        information_schema.STATISTICS 
    GROUP BY
        TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME,INDEX_TYPE,NON_UNIQUE 
) ndx1 INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME,INDEX_TYPE,
        IF(NON_UNIQUE, 'NO', 'YES') IS_UNIQUE,
        GROUP_CONCAT( 
        CONCAT('`',COLUMN_NAME,'`') 
        ORDER BY IF( INDEX_TYPE = 'BTREE'
        , SEQ_IN_INDEX
        , 0) 
        , COLUMN_NAME
        ) COLUMNS 
    FROM
        information_schema.STATISTICS 
    GROUP BY
        TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,INDEX_NAME,INDEX_TYPE,NON_UNIQUE 
) ndx2
ON ndx1.TABLE_SCHEMA = ndx2.TABLE_SCHEMA
AND ndx1.TABLE_NAME = ndx2.TABLE_NAME 
AND ndx1.INDEX_NAME != ndx2.INDEX_NAME
AND ndx1.INDEX_TYPE = ndx2.INDEX_TYPE 
AND CASE 
WHEN ndx1.COLUMNS = ndx2.COLUMNS
AND (ndx1.IS_UNIQUE = 'NO'
OR ndx1.IS_UNIQUE = ndx2.IS_UNIQUE)
THEN TRUE 
WHEN ndx1.INDEX_TYPE = 'BTREE' -- when BTREE 
AND INSTR(ndx2.COLUMNS, ndx1.COLUMNS) = 1
AND ndx1.IS_UNIQUE = 'NO'
THEN TRUE 
ELSE FALSE 
END 
GROUP BY ndx1.TABLE_SCHEMA,ndx1.TABLE_NAME,REDUNDANT_INDEX_NAME
;
```

Obviously, the indexes with the least column per grouping need to be eliminated

## Find unused indexes on the basis of selectivity.

I have not done much with unused indexes in my developer days. I try to make only necesssary indexes that match the following clauses:

- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- ORDER BY

In the event you have to cleanup a database by hunting down unused indexes, please read these:

- Use Percona-Server rather than MySQL because Percona-Server has addition information_schema tables that record index usage since mysql startup.

  - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/06/26/check-unused-keys-a-tool-to-interact-with-index_statistics/
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3243517/491757
- A very ancient tool called [**mysqlidxchk**](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlidxchk)

## Monitor the Server Parameters (What should be important parameters)

- [Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty)*100.0/[Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total) : Pct of InnoDB Buffer Pool That Needs to Be Flushed (I would keep my eye on server load if this exceeds 5%)
- (100.0 * (Delta([Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests)) - Delta([Innodb_buffer_pool_reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_reads)))) / Delta([Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests) : Read Efficiency Of InnoDB
- 100.0 * (1.0 - (Delta([Key_reads]) / Delta([Key_read_requests])) : Read Efficiency Of MyISAM (should be above 90%, anything less look into caching data with memcached or switching to InnoDB)

This is just a sample of the kind of global status values to monitor. Please read [MySQL Documentation on the Server Status Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-status-variables.html).

## Execute MySQL Server performance tuning script

Most straightforward script is mysqltuner.pl Just get it and run it

```
# wget mysqtuner.pl
# perl mysqltuner.pl
```

## Slow logs

Slow logs can be quite helpful in a low-traffic environment. Unfortunately, I have seen too many occurrences of the following

- High number of DB Connections
- All Connections Running the Same Type of Query
- Query in one connections blocking dozens of others needing the same table or row (even with InnoDB due to [deadlocking issues associated with the Clustered Index when doing UPDATEs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4470/877))

Given this scenario, I have queries that work standalone with blazing speed grind to a halt when an inundiation of queries needing common tables.

IMHO the slow query log actually does you no good becase *it records completed queries* that are regarded as slow. What you really want to do is catch long-running queries in the act of being long-running. Therefore, I would recommend using [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-query-digest.html) to pool the processlist (or tmpdump) for queries running amok. [I wrote a post back in December 2011 on how to script a crontab job that polls the processlist](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9881/877) every 20 minutes using [**mk-query-digest**](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-digest.html) (pt-query-digest can be inserted in it place).