# Table cache hit rate is 0% - is that a huge concern?

Tags: mysql

Hi all of a sudden my server has slowed to a crawl, queries that were 0.10 of a second consistently now taking 20 seconds.  somewhat randomly, sometimes it snaps right back.  so I have a really sudden and harsh performance problem.

I ran mysqltuner.pl and it reported one thing that might be a problem :

```
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (400 open / 1M opened)
```

I am just starting to delve into this performance problem, but does anyone know if this a big immediate red flag?

I can do some DD but am pressed right now.  any help much appreciated.

Don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this problem when a table being frequently table scanned no longer fits in memory.  Instead of reading data from cache, the data is read from disk.  This will flush data out on a LRU (Least Recently Used) basis.  As a result you will be constantly reading the data back in for the next table scan cycle.

If you have it available run `sar` to determine which disk partition has high IO.  This is more useful if you have distributed your database over more than one disk or partition.  Also check to see if memory is being paged heavily.

Check your slow queries log and run explain plans on the queries.  This should help identify the problem table.

A similar problem can happen if you no longer have enough free memory to keep the database buffers in memory.   This will cause part or all of the database's memory to be paged out.  It will soon be paged in.  This is often called thrashing.

Comment: Hi Bill thx for the response.  I only have one disk partition, which is an SDD.

Comment: the SDD looks like this :

Comment: /dev/sda1      156030876 16166480 132052556  11% /data

Comment: Is there an advantage of spreading a database across multiple disk partitions?  disks are so big now, that I thought doing that was obviated.  If one were to do so, would you try and put different tables on certain partitions?  Note : I would think this becomes harder in a RAID environment.  then again, maybe the RAID lets you do this.  will investigate sar (not currently installed on system).  thx again for the reply.

Comment: Spreading databases over multiple disks is done to provide allow higher throughput.  Splitting index and data partitions on different disks allows data to be read or written on one disk whie to complete while other disk is performing a seek.  RAID can provide similar benefits in slitting I/O across disks.  SSDs minimize seek time, so splitting across disks may not be as beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

The query cache was only hit 400 out of 1,000,000 times.

That is a query cache hitrate of 0.04 %

This indicates that 99.96% of your queries are unique and are not reusable. That's not unusual if your are storing session data, doing blogging, audit trails, or just plain logging of events.

While you could setup slow query logging, there is a better approach to checking on SQL performance. [I recommend using pt-query-digest with --processlist option or --tcpdump option](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9881/877)

This will allow you to catch bad queries in the act of being bad.

Comment: Most of my database access is thru stored procedures.   I believe this is the culprit.  'selects' snap back so fast frankly it almost scares me.  The problem I have is writing.  I wrote a post on it here.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20372/capabilities-of-innodb-insert-performance

Comment: by the way I am on Percona.  not sure if that impacts your choice on suggested SQL Performance tools?

Answer (score 1):

There are many things to look at, including:

- [Explain plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)
- Making sure your tables are [well indexed](http://www.slideshare.net/osscube/indexing-the-mysql-index-key-to-performance-tuning)
- Making sure your system has [adequate RAM and CPU](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/identifying-resource-bottlenecks-memory-2009-04-02/)

I'd suggest turning on the "slow-query-log" ASAP:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Also look at these parameters:

- http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/mysqlperformance.htm

Comment: well, I know which queries are taking a long time as I said "queries that were 0.10 of a second consistently now taking 20 seconds".  indicies are being used on all tables in these queries.  It just went off a cliff with no warning!  thx.